# Fluid layout with CSS

Tags: css, fluid-layout, liquid-layout

I have a page that has 10 divs acting as big buttons that are displaying in 2 rows of 5 but I would like it so that if the page is resized or it is opened on a device with a smaller screen the layout of the buttons changes automatically but I'm not sure how to go about this.

Where should I start looking or does anyone know any good tutorials that could help me achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: So what should happen when the page is resized? Do you want to have the same 2 rows of 5 but with smaller divs?

Comment: Hi, I would like the divs to rearrange themselves into new rows, say 3x3 plus 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name for that is Reactive (or Responsive) Design. You can find a decent intro to it here: http://netuncovered.com/2011/05/reactive-web-design/

It all comes down to @media queries in the CSS to determine the size of the window you're dealing with, and changing styles accordingly. Something like:

```
@media screen and (min-width:768px)
{
    .my_div { width: 200px; }
}
@media screen and (min-width:1024px)
{
    .my_div { width: 300px; }
}
```

This example gives you different sizes for the divs based on the window size. You can do the same w/ positioning or any other CSS rule based on the size of the screen using @media queries.

For the specific question of how do you change the number of items in a row, let's say you have the following HTML:

```
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="clear3"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="clear5"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="clear3"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="clear3"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

You can specify, depending on the size of the viewport, when the class .clear3 or .clear5 will *actually* clear floats. Something like:

```
.item { float: left; width: 200px; }
@media screen and (min-width:768px)
{
    .clear3 { clear: both; }
    .clear5 { clear: none; }
}
@media screen and (min-width:1024px)
{
    .clear3 { clear: none; }
    .clear5 { clear: both; }
}
```

That will change the number of divs per row of .item divs you have, based on the size of the screen. I think. I didn't really test it.

Answer (score 2):

Responsive design: This is how I learned it-

Paid but totally worth it:
http://www.codeschool.com/courses/journey-into-mobile

Type up the Twiiter Bootstap responsive section to get a feel for how they work,
I learned quite a bit doing that:
https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/responsive-768px-979px.less

You're gonna want to familiarize yourself with media queries:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@media

There is min-width and max-width helpers that respond to page size.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've heard good things about codeschool, I shall take a look

Answer (score 2):

Excellent article on how to start responsive design:

http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/04/23/responsive-web-design-layouts-and-media-queries/

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without any media queries

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper { max-width: 750px; overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid #000; margin: 50px auto; }
#wrapper div { width: 150px; height: 150px; float: left; }
```